# Access Control List ACL to Limit an Account

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, acl

How do I create an ACL in Windows 7 that prevents a public account (called Users) on our Media PC from being able to Read/Write to a particular folder while still allowing me to connect to it over our home network to move, rename, or delete files?

We have a 5-year old, and he keeps accidentally deleting shows in our Videos folder.

As you can see from the attached image, I have set the Users account to Read only, but I am still able to move, rename, or delete files in this folder from this account. I need to stop that!

If I remove Read/Write for Everyone, then I am unable to do anything that involves Write access from my PC.

[image: pic of acl that does not work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess as I can't test this, can you block everyone and then give access to those you want? Or, remove the Users group totally? And change from a home network to a public network as I assume that is W7?

Also, don't use the sharing tab, use the security tab. It should give you more control for this.

Comment: I can block everyone; however, if I do this, I have not found a way to grant permissions to my account on another PC. I am trying to give Everyone Read/Write access specifically so that I can manage files on our Home Theater PC while the family is using it.

Comment: When you right click on the folder, can you get to security? If so, just add the user and explicitly block them

Comment: The user is added and is explicitly blocked (see account named `Users` in original question), but it seems granting Read/Write to `Everyone` takes priority.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I agree - Sharing and security are different.things - the screenshot is the sharing tab - this has nothing to do per-se with security other than it will automatically set up security based upon the share. Therefore, right clicking on the folder and going to security MAY give you more options?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I had to wait until a time when the family wasn't watching TV, but I think I got it! :) After granting Read/Execute, I had to DENY the ability to Delete.

Comment: Glad it is working for you